# What is the difference between `#include` and `extern` while import a extern variable to local?

Tags: c

While using the `errno`, I once read words that

> It is important to include **`errno.h`** rather than providing your own
>   **`extern int errno`**, since **`errno`** is implemented in a thread-safe
>   manner that is more than just a simple global **`int`**.

How does the **thread-safe** manner impact the difference between `#include` and `extern` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the extern vs #include that matters

errno is defined in the header as

```
int*    _errno(void);
#define errno       (*_errno())
```

Each thread has it's own errno in it's own address space

Comment: I'd say the important thing is that there *isn't* a single `errno` shared across all threads. `_errno` returns a different address according to what thread it's called in.

Comment: @SteveJessop - yes, sorry i was writing gibberish!

Answer (score 3):

> In POSIX.1, errno is defined as an external global variable. But this
>   definition is unacceptable in a multithreaded environment, because its
>   use can result in nondeterministic results. The problem is that two or
>   more threads can encounter errors, all causing the same errno to be
>   set. Under these circumstances, a thread might end up checking errno
>   after it has already been updated by another thread.
>
> To circumvent the resulting nondeterminism, POSIX.1c redefines errno
>   as a service that can access the per-thread error number as follows
>   (ISO/IEC 9945:1-1996, §2.4):
>
> Some functions may provide the error number in a variable accessed through the symbol errno. The symbol errno is defined by including the
>   header , as specified by the C Standard ... For each thread
>   of a process, the value of errno shall not be affected by function
>   calls or assignments to errno by other threads.
>
> In addition, all POSIX.1c functions avoid using errno and, instead,
>   return the error number directly as the function return value, with a
>   return value of zero indicating that no error was detected. This
>   strategy is, in fact, being followed on a POSIX-wide basis for all new
>   functions.

http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/reentrant.html

Answer (score 2):

The quoted doc warns you that you should not *assume* that `errno` is implemented as

```
extern int errno;
```

in the `<errno.h>` header, that's all.

Obviously, an include file may contain things other than `extern` in it; in this case, the implementors took precautions to make `errno` behave in thread-safe way, but that's an unnecessary detail. The truly must-know thing is that you must include `errno.h`.

If you are really curious about the details, bring up your `errno.h` in an editor, and take a look. However, you need to remember that implementations on other systems may (and often will) be different.

Answer (score 0):

At least at mysystem, it is defined as `#define errno (*__error())`, i.e., it is calculated be `error`which returns a pointer to the correct result. In this way, you could implement a thread safe `errno`.